# How to stop Gravity Form submission from saving to local database?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a GF form that is being used to submit through an API to an external DB.
How do I stop the submission from also saving to the local WordPress GF tables?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add this to your functions.php file
(Change '1' to the id of your form):

```
    add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'remove_form_entry' );
    function remove_form_entry( $entry ) {
        GFAPI::delete_entry( $entry['id'] );
    }
```